# Stumped by CodeIgniter controllers found but not found

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

OK, I admit it.  I'm a CI newbie.  I'm doing something really basic wrong and I've been at it for a couple of hours and can't find my error.

I have a controller called login.  It's in the resources folder in my controllers folder.  It loads a view called login_form.  But for the life of me it will not load if I go to domain.com/resources/login or domain.com/resources/index.  But I can get to it via a route:

```
$route['engineering-resources/login'] = "resources/login";
```

Even when I get to it this way, my form action isn't found.  Here is my form:

```
<?php 
    echo form_open('resources/login/validate_credentials'); //folder/controller/method.  I think this is where my problem is
    echo form_input('username', 'Username');
    echo form_password('password', 'Password');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');
    echo form_close();
    ?>
```

The path is my resources folder in my controllers folder, and the controller is the login controller using the validate_credentials method. Here is the pertinent part of my login controller:

```
class Login extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Engineering Resources | Login';
        $data['main_content'] = 'resources/login_form';
        $this->load->view('templates/main.php', $data);

    }

    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('login/membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('resources/members_area');
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

The index function works when I use the route, but not when I use the above domain.com paths.  I assume that is why it cannot find the validate_credentials method.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is main.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header.php'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/nav.php'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: first of all, remove the `.php` when loading your main view. Also what are you doing inside your main view? it seems that you are sending the "path" of your login form view!! what is your folder structure inside your controller folder? also you are not validations the user inputs?! or do you in the model?

Comment: I'll remove the .php.  I posted main view above.  This is a templated approach that tells the template to load the login form into the template.  Folder structure:  controllers/resources.  Other similar paths work fine.  Maybe a problem for a form path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['engineering-resources/login'] = "resources/login";
```

This does not route to `engineering-resources/login/validate_credentials` to `resources/login/validate_credentials`

You should have something like this:

```
// not tested
$route['engineering-resources/login/(\S*)'] = "resources/login/$1";
```

One more thing is that if you are using routes, you should use the routes from your views too..

```
echo form_open('engineering-resources/login/validate_credentials');
```

Comment: That's what I needed.  Thanks, Thorpe!

Comment: What is the (\S*) in your route above and what does the $1 do?

Comment: `\s*` is a regex to match any string after /login.  `$1` tells the route to append the string to the URL.

Comment: Another question if I want to redirect the the resources folder, login controller, members_area method, do I do redirect('resources/login/members_area'); ?

Comment: you should redirect to `engineering-resources/login/members_area`